# Intellij Idea: Editing Groovy code stored in database

Tags: database, groovy, intellij-idea, editor

I have business logic coded in Groovy and stored in a database table. I would love to edit this code inside Intellij IDEA with all the code completion possibilities etc. provided by this great IDE.

I could copy the script from the database table into a temporary file; edit it and store it back into the database. I could also write a plugin. But is there maybe already a way to do this with IDEA?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you can create "External tool", calling a simple import/export script, that will allow you to automate some tasks, you'd like.

Writing plugin isn't very simple task, and is an overhead as I think.

Also, you can use some wrapper inside your application, to work with debug configuration, when buisness logic scripts are loaded directly from files. It will also allow you to autoreload them, using groovy integration features. [GroovyScriptEngine](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Embedding+Groovy)